# Searching for links in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, special-characters

I have some link broken on my site and I need to change a lot of links. My initial idea was to go through MySQL and replace strings like `<a href="/old-link/">` with `<a href="/new-link/">`.

When I go to Database - Search and enter Search for: `<a href="/old-link/">`, select all tables and choose Exact Match, nothing is found. If I choose Any word instead of Exact match, it founds many irrelevant results.

I want to search for exact match for string `<a href="/old-link/">` in order to ensure that i don't replace something that mustn't be replaced.

I suspect that nothing is found because many special symbols like <>""// are used in my search, but I can't google any coherent info as to how to put the query correctly. Can somebody help me with this?

P.S. I've also run through topics that were suggested by stackoverflow during creation of this question, but didn't find an answer

P.P.S I updated post with "code" markup as I didn't know it had to be done beforehand

Comment: UPDATE yourTable 
SET 
    yourColumn = REPLACE(yourColumn,
        'href="/old-link/"',
        'href="/new-link/");

Comment: the problem is, it's complex internet-shop cms and with a lot of tables, and i want to find which tables contain these links first, and then replace them

Comment: ,,  You an simple create a script , like create an array of all the tables and pass the table name and column name dynamically inside the loop and execute it once.. 
This wont even take much time...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the sql `replace` function

```sql
UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = REPLACE(yourColumn, 'href="/old-link/"', 'href="/new-link/");
```

Solution Provided by @PunitGajjar

Comment: Copy Paste..... :-D

Comment: yes lol, I give you credit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the comment, you can go with some loops like below.
This is an example with a PHP script.
You can use the same kind of logic with the whatever technologies you are using.

Suggesting you to create an array just because there are chances that you may not have same column name in all the tables you wish to update.

```
$myArray = [
    "table_one" => "table_one_column",
    "table_two" => "table_two_column",
    "table_three" => "table_three_column",
    "table_four" => "table_four_column"
];

foreach ($myArray as $tableName => $columName){
    /* Your query execution */
    $query = "UPDATE ".$tableName." SET ".$columName." = REPLACE(".$columName.", 'href=\"/old-link/\"', 'href=\"/new-link/\");";
}
```